# Is it possible to make matplotlib graph axes scale equally?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm attempting to make a graph in matplotlib, containg values from 5-5120, however instead of scaling equally, making a nice curve like it should, it unequally scales the x-axis, making it look linear.

[image: EggSUM]

Using multiple axes scaling tools, to no avail. When trying to change the axes, I obtain this error `MatplotlibDeprecationWarning: Adding an axes using the same arguments as a previous axes currently reuses the earlier instance.  In a future version, a new instance will always be created and returned.  Meanwhile, this warning can be suppressed, and the future behavior ensured, by passing a unique label to each axes instance.`

````py
# plotting the points
plt.plot(n, m)

# naming the x axis
plt.xlabel('X')
# naming the y axis
plt.ylabel('Y')

# giving a title to my graph
plt.title('test')
plt.axes().set_aspect(aspect=1)


# function to show the plot
plt.show()```
````

Comment: you must be plotting a list/strings and not actual numbers..can you show your x and y data

Comment: The warning is unrelated, it tells you that `plt.axes()` creates a new axes. You probably want to use `plt.gca()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use `plt.xticks(n)`:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
# plotting the points
n = [1,50, 250, 1000, 5210]
m = [1,2,3,4,5]
plt.plot(n, m)

# naming the x axis
plt.xlabel('X')
# naming the y axis
plt.ylabel('Y')

# giving a title to my graph
plt.title('test')
plt.xticks(n)
plt.show()
```

It shows something like this:

[image]

Comment: I had a spelling mistake in my code, please try again.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to use:

```
plt.gca().set_aspect('equal', adjustable='box')
```

or

```
plt.axis('equal')
```

or

```
plt.axis('scaled')
```